# Can I use 2 msal-angular login with different clientID and authority in one application?

Tags: angular, authentication, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

Can I use 2 msal-angular login with different clientID and authority in one application? I can login with msal to my app and i can login without msal. When i am in aplication there is some functional for which you must login with msal but to another Azure active directory.